# How to install & use jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

What i did so far:

**Step1:** installed "jQuery.UI.Combined" via NuGet
**Step2:** In my Razorpage I include this code:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").click(function () {
            $("#NavBar_OptionPanel").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Step3:** This is my Button:

```
<a id="test">Settings</a>
```

**Step4:** This is the Panel i want to toggle on/off:

```
<div id="NavBar_OptionPanel">
    <label>Options</label>
</div>
```

**What i expected:** When clicking on an element with id="test", all elements with id="NavBar_OptionPanel" should toggle on/off

But nothing is happening. So i guess there could be two problems:

1. The installation of jQuery is wrong/a step missing
2. The usage of jQuery is wrong

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the console for errors?

Comment: `Step1: installed "jQuery.UI.Combined" via NuGet` That's a problem right there.  jQuery != jQuery.UI.  There's a package called jQuery - install that instead.

Comment: no errors as far as i can see (i looked into the output window & show output  = ASP.net core webserver)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your code inside your script tag including jquery, change it to this:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").click(function () {
            $("#NavBar_OptionPanel").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: that was the problem + installing the wrong package like @Archer said. Thank you for your help